# Updating wxWidgets Radio Item Dynamically

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, menuitem, radio-group

I'm trying to dynamically change the state of a group of radio items and I could not figure out how to do it. I attached my code and the CMakeLists.txt file below. When the Test method is called, I expect the radio item 3 to be the checked, but radio item 1 remains checked. Can anyone show me where do I do wrong?

Thank you.

```
#CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(menu_radio_item)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
   include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
   add_executable(radio_item main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(radio_item ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
endif(wxWidgets_FOUND)
```

Code:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

// Application class declaration
class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
DECLARE_APP(MyApp)

// Frame class declaration
#define wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1 wxID_HIGHEST + 1
#define wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2 wxID_HIGHEST + 2
#define wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3 wxID_HIGHEST + 3
#define wxID_TEST         wxID_HIGHEST + 4

class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnRadioItemPressed(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnTest(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnRadioItemUpdate(wxUpdateUIEvent& event);
private:
    wxMenuBar *menubar;
    wxMenu *file;
    int item_controller;
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

// Application class implementation
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame(wxT("Simple Menu and Toolbar"));
    frame->Show();
    return true;
}

// Frame class definition
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, MyFrame::OnQuit)
EVT_MENU(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1, MyFrame::OnRadioItemPressed)
EVT_MENU(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2, MyFrame::OnRadioItemPressed)
EVT_MENU(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3, MyFrame::OnRadioItemPressed)
EVT_MENU(wxID_TEST, MyFrame::OnTest)
EVT_UPDATE_UI(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1, MyFrame::OnRadioItemUpdate)
EVT_UPDATE_UI(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2, MyFrame::OnRadioItemUpdate)
EVT_UPDATE_UI(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3, MyFrame::OnRadioItemUpdate)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title) :
    wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(280, 180)),
    item_controller(1) {
    menubar = new wxMenuBar;
    file = new wxMenu;
    file->Append(wxID_EXIT, wxT("&Quit"));
    file->AppendSeparator();
    file->AppendRadioItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1, wxT("One"));
    file->AppendRadioItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2, wxT("Two"));
    file->AppendRadioItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3, wxT("Tree"));
    file->AppendSeparator();
    file->Append(wxID_TEST, wxT("Test"));
    menubar->Append(file, wxT("&File"));
    SetMenuBar(menubar);
    Centre();
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnRadioItemPressed(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    if(event.GetId() == wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1) {
        std::cout << "Item 1 is pressed" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(event.GetId() == wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2) {
        std::cout << "Item 2 is pressed" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(event.GetId() == wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3) {
        std::cout << "Item 3 is pressed" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No match!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnRadioItemUpdate(wxUpdateUIEvent& event) {
    std::cout << "OnRadioItemUpdate" << std::endl;
    wxMenuItem* item;
    switch(item_controller) {
    case 1:
        item = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1);
        item->Check(true);
        break;
    case 2:
        item = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2);
        item->Check(true);
        break;
    case 3:
        item = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3);
        item->Check(true);
        break;
    }
    /*
    std::cout << "OnRadioItemUpdate" << std::endl;
    switch(event.GetId()) {
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1:
         event.Check(item_controller == 1);
         break;     
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2:
         event.Check(item_controller == 2);
         break;     
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3:
         event.Check(item_controller == 3);
         break;
    }   
    */
}



void MyFrame::OnTest(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    item_controller = 3;
    UpdateWindowUI();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change the state of anything directly from `wxEVT_UPDATE_UI` handlers, this is not how it works. You need to call `event.Check()` instead to indicate whether the item for which the event is being handled should be checked or not. As a consequence of this, you can't reuse the same handler for all the items -- unless you want all of them to be enabled or disabled at the same time, that is.

It is, on one hand, much simpler than you think, but on the other hand very different too. Update UI mechanism is "functional" in nature: you don't change the state, you just define what the state should be.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_update_u_i_event.html) and, maybe more usefully, look at the examples of using `wxUpdateUIEvent` in the samples code (just grep them for it) to see how it should be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I could not find any example with the radio buttons. In my code I have other menu items which work. I've already read the documentation and nothing about radio buttons. And one issue with the radio buttons is that once you change one of them, the UI update callbacks are called for all three.

Comment: You must *not* change them if you use `wxEVT_UPDATE_UI`. It doesn't matter whether you use it with radio buttons or anything else. You should never do anything else than calling `event.Check()` or `event.Enable()` and so on in your handler.

Comment: Hi,  I changed the handler as you suggested (as far as I understood) but it does not work either. `void MyFrame::OnRadioItemUpdate(wxUpdateUIEvent& event) {
    std::cout << "OnRadioItemUpdate" << std::endl;
    switch(event.GetId()) {
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_1:
        event.Check(item_controller == 1);
        break;
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_2:
        event.Check(item_controller == 2);
        break;
    case wxID_RADIO_ITEM_3:
        event.Check(item_controller == 3);
        break;
    }
}`

Comment: This is pretty unreadable but if I decipher it correctly, it should work (although it would be much clearer to write this as 3 separate handlers)...

Comment: I edited the code, and add the new implementation in the:    OnRadioItemUpdate(wxUpdateUIEvent& event) function as a comment. I tried it and it does not work. May be the code is correct but the wxWidgets has a bug for updating radio menus.

Comment: Then please try reproducing the bug with minimal changes to the menu sample and opening a ticket on http://trac.wxwidgets.org/. Be sure to mention the platform and version of wxWidgets you use.